# House of the Sea

Tags: single-word-requests

Growing up far from the sea, the little make-shift restaurants along the beach in summer are new to me.  A Japanese friend asked what they are called in English. My search resulted in "cabana" and "shack".  Japanese call them *umi no ie* or "House of the Sea".  Is there an English word or phrase that describes these unique little temporary structures?

Here is a link to one example. 
http://rmake.jp/published_items/1421

Comment: Are these little temporary restaurants in Japan?  Could you describe them, for example, do they have four walls and a door in addition to a roof, or are they open on one or more sides?  They sound charming.

Comment: Can you [edit] this to add some photos?

Comment: A "beach restaurant," a "beach cafe" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beach+restaurants%2Cbeach+cafes%2Cbeach+restaurant%2Cbeach+cafe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeach%20restaurants%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeach%20cafes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeach%20restaurant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeach%20cafe%3B%2Cc0; https://www.google.fr/search?q=beach+cafe&prmd=imsvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB_ebOisTLAhWqC5oKHQfoAkwQ_AUIBygB&biw=546&bih=359&dpr=2

Comment: Depends on what's being served.  Sometimes they can be "crab shacks" or "lobster shacks"  https://www.google.com/search?q=lobster+shack&biw=1366&bih=714&tbm=isch  although maybe you're thinking more *temporary* than that.

Answer (score 2):

These can be commonly named [Tiki hut](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tiki+hut&biw=1134&bih=629&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXssKWjcTLAhXCTCYKHZRfBzAQsAQIUw), Tiki Bar or Tiki restaurant.

Comment: I think you are right, but you should have added more information so that the OP and other users could judge whether you are right.  I added a link to photographs of Tiki huts, which is the minimum needed to flesh out your answer.

Comment: Oceania? Maori? or across the Pacific?

Comment: Tiki hut may be the closest English expression for these Japanese restaurants.  Similar restaurants are popular in South Korea but the style of seating, foods, and location are different.